# Periodic backup of MySQL database through crontab set from PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron

I have given an option to schedule periodic mysql dumps through my php application.
Crontab is set for the user 'www-data' as follows :

```
1 * * * * mysqldump --user=root --password=1 --host=localhost dbname > /var/www/myapp/../backups/db_`date '+%F-%H-%M-%S'`.sql
```

When I do `crontab -u www-data -l` I can see the above cron.

The problem is that this cron is not being executed. It should execute every 1 minute right ?
Also I have set the permissions for the `/var/www` as 777. Still the file is not created.

```
mysqldump --user=root --password=1 --host=localhost dbname > /var/www/myapp/../backups/db_`date '+%F-%H-%M-%S'`.sql
```

When I type this in terminal the file is created fine. The problem is with the cron job only. Please help.

### UPDATE

I changed it to

```
* * * * * mysqldump --user=root --password=1 --host=localhost dbname > /var/www/myapp/../backups/db_`date '+%F-%H-%M-%S'`.sql
```

even now it is not working

Comment: `1 * * * *` is "run at 1-minute-past-the-hour, every hour". To get it to run "once a minute", change to just `* * * * *`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @newfurniturey. The thing is that in my application there is a select box where the user can select from 1 minute, 15 minutes, 30 minutes or 1 hour interval for backup.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes crontab soesn't have all the environment variables a regular shell would have.

Maybe it doesn"t know where to find mysqldump. Could you try giving the full path to the command, like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump --user=root --password=1 --host=localhost dbname > /var/www/myapp/../backups/db_`date '+%F-%H-%M-%S'`.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The cron you have listed should execute on the 1st minute of every hour.

I do something similar with a simple python script:

```
import os
os.system('dump command for database1')
os.system('dump command for database2')
```

It keeps everything organized for me. I run the script on a cronjob.

```
1 * * * * python /path/to/script
```

Comment: Sorry I need it to run every 1 minute.

Comment: Depending on how large the database is or is going to become, there are some serious questions about the real need to back a database up every 60 seconds. What's the risk/loss of losing all the data you have saved for the last hour or two? Perhaps an hourly/daily backup would fit the situation better?